# Ensure static storage for a function parameter

Tags: c, gcc

We have this function prototype:

```
  BNode *b_new_node(const char *name, int pos, int len, const char *val);
```

Most of the code using this(and similar) are autogenerated code, and looks like:

```
 b = b_new_node("foo.bar.id.1", 0, 10, some_data);
```

The function allocates a new BNode and copies the  `val` string into it, but it just assigns the `name` member to a pointer, e.g.

```
 b_strlcpy(new_node->val, val, sizeof new_node->val);
 new_node->name = name;
```

This wrecks havoc if the first argument in b_new_node("foo.bar.id.1", 0, 10, some_data); is not a string literal, or otherwise something with static storage duration, but e.g. a buffer on the stack.

Is there anyway, with gcc (other compilers are of interest too), we can have a compile time check that this argument is passed in is of static storage ?

(ofcourse the easy way to avoid these possible problems is to copy that argument too into the node - the measurements we did with that approach rises the memory need by 50% and slows the program down by 10%, so that approach is undesirable).

Comment: Sorry not to answer a good question, but: Are you sure you need a *static* string? A string that lives longer than the node would suffice, I think? The classic way of solving this is documentation about the expected lifetime of `name`'s contents, and programmers reading the documentation. Suboptimal, I know, but the standard.

Comment: @thiton Sure, in principle you only need something that lives longer than the node. But since most of the code using this is auto generated, with a string literal, and the fact that detecting a string literal or static storage sounds like an easier job for a compiler than tracking arbitary object lifetime - that'll be a suitable approach.

Comment: @larsmans surely that question seems to be about runtime checking ?  the OP seem to only need a compile time check.

Answer (score 1):

This will detect string literals:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT_IT(c) do {\
if (__builtin_constant_p(c))\
    print_it(c, 1);\
else \
    1/__builtin_constant_p(c);\
} while (0)


void print_it(const char *c, int is_static)
{
    printf("%s is a constant %d\n", c, is_static);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char bar[] = "bar";
    PRINT_IT("Foo"); //line 19
    PRINT_IT(bar);   //line 20

return 0;

}


$ gcc  foo.c 
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:20: warning: division by zero
```

So you can wrap your b_new_node() function in a macro, perhaps just for a debug build, and harness the division by zero warnings.

Note that it only detects string literals as "arguments", not static storage, e.g.

```
const char *foo = "foo";
PRINT_IT(foo); //will generate a warning
PRINT_IT("foo"); //will not generate a warning
PRINT_IT(global_foo); //will generate a warning, even when. 
                      //global_foo is const char *foo = "foo"; or
                      //global_foo is const char foo[] = "foo";
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally no; there is no C-provided facility to know whether or not a pointer points to something in static storage. Specific environments and data structures may change the circumstances - such as checking if the pointed-to address is in a [read-only memory segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_only_memory).

## Saving space by countering duplication

To eliminate duplicated values, as pointed to by `name`, you could use [the flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) which is not very different from [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Basically you build a central set of encountered tokens and store only the reference to each token. The references could be array indices or pointers.

To be able to clean-up quickly, you could combine the flyweight pattern with [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) where a count of zero, means no references left.

To keep performance of the central store high, use a data structure where look-up is fast such as a set, or with a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) if [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `BNode` conditionally copy the name. That will require and extra bit of storage in `BNode`. E.g.:

```
typedef struct BNode {
    char const* name;
    unsigned char : own_name;
} BNode;

void b_copy_name(BNode* n) {
    if(!n->own_name) {
        char* p = strdup(n->name);
        if(p) {
            n->own_name = 1;
            n->name = p;
        }
        else {
            abort();
        }
    }
}

void b_destroy(BNode* n) {
    // ...
    if(n->own_name) 
         free(n->name);
}
```

Comment: While a possibility, this requires the programmer to do the right thing, instead of having the compiler check that fact. It seems that __builtin_constant_p() could help me, but I don't have it quite working yet..

Comment: @user964970 In this case `__builtin_constant_p` can only be used at the call site, i.e. again the programmer should do the right thing, or wrap it in a macro.